# Replacing Core 2 Duo processor with Core i5 processor

Tags: gaming

Can I replace my Core 2 Duo processor with Core i5 processor
on a Core 2 Duo motherboard? 
If I can’t, what adjustment do I need to do to make it possible?

Answer (score 7):

The simple answer: No, you can't. You'll need a whole new computer.

The complex answer (in Intel land; AMD is a bit different):

- A motherboard will not support a newer CPU without a firmware (BIOS/UEFI) update. But this doesn't matter here because...
- The sockets are incompatible (note that the Core-i3/5/7 lineage went through *many* sockets, none of which are compatible with Core 2). There is simply no way it will work. The physical connections cannot be changed. Which means...
- You need a new motherboard. But motherboards of that generation are DDR2 RAM, while a modern Core-i5 will be either DDR4 or DDR3. Which means...
- You also need new RAM.

Shopping list, assuming you already have the new CPU:

- New motherboard that supports the CPU
- New RAM that works on the new motherboard

What you might be able to keep:

- Old HDD (though, upgrade to SSD is heavily recommended)
- Old video card (if it's gaming, upgrade is recommended. If it's low-end, you may as well use the new on-CPU graphics, which will be better).
- Case and PSU
- Peripherals (monitor, keyboard, mouse)